# axis length (not scaling!) in a scatter plot

Tags: r

How to change the axis length? for ex:

```
s <- data.table(school=rep(1:3,5), wave=c(rep(1,7), rep(2,8)), v1=rpois(15,10))
plot(s$wave,s$v2)
```

I get a scatter plot where the data is at the edges of the plot (a lot of white space in the graph). changing the xaxp values doesn't help (tried `xaxp=c(-1, +2,4)`) but nothing happened) and when I try to define it a factor I get a box plot. I know I can "squeeze" it when i save to .png but is there any other way?

I tried to upload pictures to convey the problem but I don't have enough reputation.
[image]

edit-thanks for whoever uploaded it (although the axis are reversed - wave is the x and V2 is the y). the thing is that there is a lot of "free space" between the 1st and the 2nd wave. the position is perfect when i define the wave a factor (it's centered and each factor is half the axis length) but it keeps giving me a box plot!

Comment: If you link the images (perhaps on imgur) someone with enough reputation can post them for you. I'm pretty unclear on your goal. If you can achieve what you want by resizing the plot window (perhaps using "zoom" in RStudio), then the answer is generally to do that interactively, and to specify the height/width when you save it to pdf/png etc.

Comment: Do you mean the y-axis limits?? Try using `ylim=c(0,3)` in the call to `plot(...)`.

Comment: So I inserted the plot, but the question still seems impossibly vague.

Comment: thank for the picture upload!! as you can tell, there is a lot of "room" between the the 1 and the 2. i would like it to look just like a box plot factors look- in the middle

Comment: did you try jhoward's suggestion?

Comment: i have but that's still not what i want. i want the same placing as it would be in a box plot with 1 and 2 as factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a lot of values to your plot function, like colour, title, and also the limits of the axsis

Your code:

```
s <- data.frame(school=rep(1:3,5), wave=c(rep(1,7), rep(2,8)), v1=rpois(15,10))
plot(s$wave,s$v2)
```

And now just add some more:

```
plot(
  x = s$wave,
  y = s$v2,
  col = "red",
  main = "This is my title",
  xlab = "the label of the x-axis",
  ylab = "the label of the y-axis",
  xlim = c(-5, 5), # the limits of the x-axis,
  ylim = c(-4, 10) # the limits of the y-axis
)
```

You can add much more like size and type of the points ...

just as jlhoward mentioned

Comment: thank you for the replay but that is not what i was looking for. i have edited the main question for better clarity. someone was nice enough to upload a pic to help me explain.

Comment: I don't know if plot() can do such a thing. Maybe you should try the ggplot2 package and then do a "facet" plot. It should then look like this ggplot(s, aes(x = wave, y = y, facet = Curve)), curve defining the facet for the curve (e.g. "a" and "b"). In the beginning the ggplot package takes some time to really get into it, however in the end it is much fast

Answer (score 0):

i found a function in the "lattice" package that does exactly what i want - a boxplot without the box.
the function is called stripplot.
http://www.math.ucla.edu/~anderson/rw1001/library/base/html/stripplot.html

thank you all for the help